# Centering object below 2 floating ones

Tags: html, css, center

I was trying to make an interesting element on my website. I was trying to have 2 circles overlapping their parent element and 1 overlapping but below. Like 2 are overlapping above and 1 is overlapping below.

I tried float left and float right but I don´t know how to deal with the 3 one. 
I could make 3 inline(in example).

Does anyone know how to make 2 inline and the 3rd one in center below them?

I hope you will understand me... it is pretty hard to describe.

```css
#bile{
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
.kolecko{
position: absolute;
 top: -10%;
 display: table;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: gray;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
}
.kolecko:hover{
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #fff;
}
.popisek{
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
font-size: 15px;

}
.popisek:hover{
color: blue;
}

.obal{
 display: inline-flex;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#rude{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 height: 250px;
 background: #720000;
 padding: 0 15%;
}

.kolecka{
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
margin-right: 10%;
}
.kolecka:last-child{
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="bile"></section>
<section id="rude">
 <div class="kolecka">
 <div class="obal">
   <div class="kolecko"> 
   <div class="popisek">WWW</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="kolecka">
  <div class="obal">
   <div class="kolecko"> 
   <div class="popisek">abs</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="kolecka">
  <div class="obal">
   <div class="kolecko" style="float: right;">
   <div class="popisek">123</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve, please take a look

```css
#bile{
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
.kolecko{
//position: absolute;
 top: -10%;
 display: table;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: gray;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
}
.kolecko:hover{
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #fff;
}
.popisek{
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
font-size: 15px;

}
.popisek:hover{
color: blue;
}

.obal{
 display: inline-flex;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#rude{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 height: 250px;
 background: #720000;
 padding: 0 15%;
}

.kolecka{
display: block;
width: 100px;
margin-right: 10%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
}
.kolecka:last-child{
 margin-right: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.kolecka:nth-child(2){
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="bile"></section>
<section id="rude">
 <div class="kolecka">
 <div class="obal">
   <div class="kolecko"> 
   <div class="popisek">WWW</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="kolecka">
  <div class="obal">
   <div class="kolecko"> 
   <div class="popisek">abs</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="kolecka">
  <div class="obal">
   <div class="kolecko" style="float: right;">
   <div class="popisek">123</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

</section>
```

Comment: quite yes... but with that special feature that the 2 upper circles will overlap/overflow over top and the 3 in middle will overflow the bottom edge of the red section....So below the red section is another white section(but I guess it doesn´t matter)

Comment: that is pretty much it, I rewrited it for my original usage and it worked but I couldnt minimize the spaces between them....I need spaces like 50px or something like this(small/medium). So which css element makes it so wide?

Comment: `.kolecka:last-child{
 margin-right: 0;
    right: 0;
}` this is the one which separates the two, increase the `right` value to reduce the spacing

Comment: Thank you... Now it looks just as I wanted